# how to run .sh file in windows with start and stop button

Tags: php, shell

I have a php file(assignlead.php) that needs to run in the background after every 5 second once click on start button and it should be stopped only after click on stop button.To do this job i have created two .sh file,one for start the job and second for stop the job.

code of start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
php -f assignlead.php
sleep 5
done
```

code of stop.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=`ps -ef | grep start.sh | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
kill -9 $pid
```

I am trying to run these code through link created as :
For start: `domain.com/start.php`
For stop: `domain.com/stop.php`

code of start.php:

```
<?php
shell_exec('./start.sh');
header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

code of stop.php:

```
<?php
shell_exec('./stop.sh');
header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

But when i click on start button i am getting internal server error.i have checked in the logs but i didn't get that,i have attached the screenshot error_log [this is the apache errorlog][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8cdN.png
```

How can I complete this job?

Comment: What happens if you run `start.sh` on the shell?

Comment: it works perfectly in shell.but it didn't work while i click on start button in windows.